# Subsequence in $W^{1,1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, sobolev-spaces

I am dealing with this exercise. [image] I don't know how to reason about it. Maybe I should prove that $\forall C>0 \exists \bar n :||u_n||_{L^\infty}>C\forall n>\bar n$.
Could you give me a hint?

Comment: Your proposed proof method definitely doesn't work because $||u_n||_{L^\infty}=1$ for all $n$. Try plotting $u_n$. It should be apparent from this what $u_n$ goes to pointwise, which must be the $L^\infty$ limit if such a limit exists. Calling this limit $u$, from there you should be able to determine $||u_n-u||_{L^\infty}$.

Comment: Ok I understand. Since $||u_n-u||_{L^{\infty}}=1 \forall n$ I deduce that it holds also for whatever subsequence which cannot converge. But how can I prove that the pointwise limit has to be eventually the same of the $L^{\infty}$ one?

Comment: This follows from the definition of the $L^\infty$ norm. If the supremum almost everywhere is less then $\epsilon$ then so is the function at almost every point.